# How to create a product in admin panel with custom module?

Tags: magento-1.7

How to create a products grid in admin panel with custom module in magento. Same as core product grid.

I want to implement same functionality in my custom module. Need help.

Comment: Follow this link. It helps you to create your own custom module as well as admin grid as you require. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Comment: @PavanKumar provided link is not valid send me the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my comment as answer because, it is getting modified if I give it in comment area. Here is the link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table